# Simple root of characteristic polynomial of matrix over a commutative ring

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, commutative-algebra, characteristic-polynomial

I'm struggling with §5 of Lombardi & Quitte's [Commutative algebra: constructive methods](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.04832.pdf). Specifically, I'm having a hard time with the proof of Lemma 5.1.

**5.1 Lemma.** Let $n\geq 2,a\in \mathbf A$ and $A\in \mathrm M_n(\mathbf A)$ be a matrix whose characteristic polynomial $f$ admits $a\in \mathbf A$ as a simple zero. Let $g=f/(x-a)$ and $K=\operatorname{Ker} (A-a\mathrm I)$ and $I=\operatorname{Im}(A-a\mathrm I)$.

1. We have $\operatorname{Ker} (A-a\mathrm I)=\operatorname{Im}g(A)$ and $\operatorname{Im}(A-a\mathrm I)=\operatorname{Ker}g(A)$.
2. The matrix $g(A)$ is of rank $1$ and $A-a\mathrm I$ is of rank $n-1$.
3. If a polynomial $R$ annihilates $A$ then $R(a)=0$ i.e $R$ is a multiple of $x-a$.
4. The principal minors of order $n-1$ of $A-a\mathrm I$ are comaximal. We localize by inverting such a minor, the matrix $g(A)$ becomes simple of rank $1$, the modules $K=\operatorname{Ker} (A-a\mathrm I)$ and $I=\operatorname{Im}(A-a\mathrm I)$ become free of rank $1$ and $n-1$.

I understand the proof of the first assertion, but I am struggling with the rest.

2. The authors show $f^\prime (0)=g(0)=\pm \sum _i \mu_i$ is the (signed) sum of the principal minors $\mu_i$ of $A$. They claim this proves the rank of $A-a\mathrm I$ is $n-1$ and also that the rank of $g(A)$ is at least one. How does this follow?
3. This is okay for me.
4. The authors write that we have already seen the $\mu_i$'s are comaximal (not a typo). First of all I don't understand why this is, and second I don't understand how it shows the minors of the matrix $A-a\mathrm I$ are comaximal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can help you with part 2 for now; part 4 involves too much terminology I have forgotten or never learned.

Just as Lombardi and Quitté do, I suppose that $a = 0$, since the general case can be transformed into this one by replacing $A$ by $A - aI_n$. Thus, the characteristic polynomial $f$ of $A$ admits $0$ as a simple zero, and we have $g = f/X$ and $h=X$ and $K = \operatorname{Ker} A$ and $I = \operatorname{Im} A$.

2. So you know that $\sum_i \mu_i = \pm f'\left(0\right)$ is invertible (since $0$ is a simple root of $f$). This shows that $\left< \mu_1, \mu_2, \ldots, \mu_n \right> = \left< 1 \right>$. Hence, the ideal generated by the $\left(n-1\right)\times\left(n-1\right)$-minors of $A$ is $\left< 1 \right>$ (since the principal minors $\mu_1, \mu_2, \ldots, \mu_n$ are among these minors). In other words, $A$ has rank $\geq n-1$. However, $A$ has rank $\leq n-1$, since $\det A = 0$ (because $0$ is a zero of the characteristic polynomial of $A$). Thus, $A$ has rank $n-1$. In other words, $h\left(A\right)$ has rank $n-1$ (since $h = X$). It remains to prove that $g\left(A\right)$ has rank $1$. However, $g\left(A\right) = \pm \widetilde{A}$ (this follows from part 6 of Lemma 1.4, because $\mathrm{C}_A = f$ satisfies $f\left(0\right) = 0$ and thus $g = \pm \Gamma_A$). Hence, we need to prove that $\widetilde{A}$ has rank $1$. Well, we know that $\widetilde{A}$ has rank $\geq 1$, since the ideal generated by the entries of $\widetilde{A}$ is $\left< 1 \right>$ (indeed, this ideal is precisely the ideal generated by the $\left(n-1\right)\times\left(n-1\right)$-minors of $A$; but we have seen that the latter ideal is $\left< 1 \right>$). It remains to show that $\widetilde{A}$ has rank $< 2$. In other words, it remains to show that any $2 \times 2$-minor of $\widetilde{A}$ is $0$. This holds for any matrix $A$ whose determinant is $0$, and follows from part 8 of Lemma 1.4 (because the $2 \times 2$-minors of $\widetilde{A}$ are the entries of $\bigwedge^2 \widetilde{A}$). Note that this also follows from the Desnanot-Jacobi identity (see, e.g., Theorem 2 in my answer at [Products of adjugate matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1396165/products-of-adjugate-matrices/1398281#1398281) ).

My impression is that the Schur complement will do the trick for part 4, but I'd have to look up the exact definition of "simple".

Comment: Dear @darij, I have a final question for you on this matter. The proofs of 5.4 & 5.5(1) are slightly convoluted, first proving 5.5(1) for the universal splitting algebra, deducing 5.4, and inferring 5.5(1) in general. What part of the proof of 5.5(1) for the universal splitting algebra fails for general extensions?

Comment: @Arrow: Are you asking why they first prove it for the generic matrix, and then specialize to an arbitrary matrix? Not every matrix is diagonalizable (even over an overring).

Comment: No, I am asking about the sentence "now note that the...". Why does it matter if we take $A_1$ to be the *universal splitting algebra* as opposed to an arbitrary extension over which the characteristic polynomial splits? It seems the authors' argument first proves 5.5(1) *only for the initial splitting algebra*, deduces 5.4, and then infers 5.5(1) for *any extension*.

Comment: Ah, that. Well, the universal splitting algebra has an explicit combinatorial basis that does not depend on $f$, and computations in it are polynomial in the coefficients of $f$. They may or may not use this in the proof.

Comment: I do not think this is implicitly used (I think they refer to your basis as the *Cauchy modules*, which are indeed defined universally). I'd really appreciate your insight here (the argument in the book is very short), since I want to make sure I'm not missing something.

Comment: They say that "the structure of the statement of the corollary, item 1, when we take $\mathbf{A}_1 = \operatorname{Adu}_{\mathbf{A},f}$, is a family of algebraic identities with the coefficients of the matrix $A$ for indeterminates". I think this does rely on the combinatorial structure of $ \operatorname{Adu}_{\mathbf{A},f}$. That said, I am not sure how well I understand their proof. Mine is slightly different (even if it uses similar ideas): Rewrite the statement of part 1 without reference to the roots $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ using symmetric polynomials (viz., fix $g$; use ...

Comment: ... the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials to write all coefficients of $\prod_{i=1}^n \left(T-g\left(x_i\right)\right)$ as polynomials in the elementary symmetric polynomials of $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$, thus as polynomials in the $\operatorname{Tr}\left(\bigwedge^k A\right)$'s, and then what you need to prove becomes visibly a bunch of polynomial identities in the entries of $A$).

Comment: Unfortunately I do not understand this argument, and they seem to derive this in 5.7 using "the same method".

Comment: You can derive 5.7 just as easily using my method.

Comment: I don't doubt it, I just don't understand how you calculate the trace of the exterior powers. Have you perhaps written this down somewhere?

Comment: Can you state your question in a new thread? I'm afraid I can't get to the core of the confusion this easily, as there are several slippery points around this.

Comment: [done](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4262012/223002)!