# Characteristic polynomials of matrix polynomials and exterior powers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, commutative-algebra

Suppose we know that the generic matrix $(x_{ij})$ is diagonalizable over a commutative ring containing $\mathbb Z[x_{11},\dots ,x_{nn}]$.

How can one deduce the following facts?

1. Suppose $A,B\in \mathrm M_n(R)$ have the same characteristic polynomial. Then for any $f\in R[x]$, so do $f(A),f(B)$.
2. Suppose the characteristic polynomial of $A\in \mathrm M_n(R)$ splits over an extension $R_1\supset R$ as $\chi_A=\prod_{i=1}^n(x-\lambda _i)$. Then for any $f\in R[x]$ we have $\chi_{f(A)}=\prod_{i=1}^n(x-f(\lambda _i))$.

5.4, 5.5 in the constructive commutative algebra book by Lombardi & Quitte outline an argument, but I am not able to follow it.

Comment: Note: "Ring" means "commutative ring" here.

Comment: (Will answer this in some days if no one else does; this takes a lot of words.)

Comment: Dear @darijgrinberg, I edited to include "commutative". Also, thank you very much.

Comment: BTW, fact 2 is known as the "(algebraic) spectral mapping theorem". There is [a paper by Ekedahl and Laksov](https://doi.org/10.1080/00029890.2004.11920116) that proves it at least for the Generic Matrix. If your problem is with that part of the proof, this may answer your question.

Comment: Thank you for the reference! I will look into it tomorrow.

Comment: In view of your previous questions, if you want a proof using constructive mathematics, please state that in the question body.

Comment: Dear @darijgrinberg, I posted an attempt. I would be happy if you could look and point out my mistakes!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the generic degree $n$ polynomial $\omega = \sum_{i=0}^n t_ix^i\in \mathbb Z[t_0,\dots ,t_n,x]$. The expression on the right below is symmetric in $x_1,\dots ,x_n$, whence there is a unique $\Omega \in \mathbb Z[t_0,\dots ,t_n,x_1,\dots ,x_n]$ satisfying $$\Omega(t_0,\dots,t_n,s_1(x_{1..n}),\dots,s_n(x_{1..n}))=\prod_{i=1}^n\omega(x_i).$$

**Theorem.** Let $\chi_A=x^n+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}c_ix^i\in \mathbb Z[x_{11},\dots,x_{nn}][x]$ be the characteristic polynomial of the generic matrix. We have the following equality in $\mathbb Z[t_0,\dots ,t_n,x_{11},\dots,x_{nn}]$.
$$\det\omega(A)=\det(A^n+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}t_iA^i)=\Omega(t_0,\dots ,t_n,-c_{n-1},\dots,(-1)^nc_0).$$

**Proof.** Pass to an extension over which $\chi_A$ is split separable with roots $\lambda_1,\dots ,\lambda_n$ and $A$ is diagonalizable. By calculation in this extension $\det \omega(A)=\prod_{i=1}^n\omega(\lambda_i)$. Specializing $x_1,\dots ,x_n$ to $\lambda_1,\dots ,\lambda_n$ gives the same result for the RHS. Hence the equation holds in the extension, whence it holds in the asserted ring.

**Corollary.** Let $A\in \mathrm M_n(R)$. Suppose $\chi_A=\prod_{i=1}^n(x-\lambda_i)$ in an extension $R\subset R_1$. For every $f\in R[x]$ we have $\det f(A)=\prod_{i=1}^nf(\lambda_i)$.

**Algebraic spectral mapping theorem.** Invoke the corollary for $R[x]$ and the polynomial $x-f(y)\in R[x,y]$.

Comment: "Specializing $x_1,\dots ,x_n$ to $\lambda_1,\dots ,\lambda_n$ gives the same result for the RHS" What do you mean by this?

Comment: @darijgrinberg I mean evaluating the first equation (defining $\Omega$) at the $\lambda _i$. This gives the RHS of the equation in the theorem.

Comment: Ah. How do you get the corollary from the theorem? Universal property of the universal splitting algebra?

Comment: I thought just by specialization.

Comment: Can you elaborate? (I have the attention span of a fly right now, but this won't get any better until winter break.)

Comment: Specialize the equality of the theorem by taking $t_0,\dots ,t_n$ to the coefficients of $f\in R[x]$, and the $x_{11},\dots,x_{nn}$ to the entries of $A\in \mathrm M_n(R)$. Now go up to the extension $R_1\supset R$. Here we can actually calculate the RHS of the equality of the theorem, using the defining equation for $\Omega$: evaluating it at the roots gives the product of the value of $f$ (the specialization of $\omega$) at the roots. Hence the theorem gives the desired assertion.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I would love your approval here :) Also, maybe (part of) [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4659878/separability-of-sums-and-products-wraiths-definition-of-formally-unramified-mo) will interest you :)

Comment: "Pass to an extension over which $\chi_A$ is split separable" How do you prove the existence of such an extension? (I understand that it's true, but I don't see this as obvious, and depending on the order in which you prove different results, it could take a dozen pages. Can you do it without polynomial factorization?)

Comment: @darijgrinberg I think I can prove the characteristic polynomial of the initial (i.e generic) matrix is the initial (generic) monic, and then by specialization that the discriminant of the initial monic is cancellable.

Comment: That's going a bit too fast for me. The charpoly of the generic matrix is not the generic monic, is it? And cancellable in a smaller ring does not imply cancellable in a larger ring? But I suspect this all works if set up correctly... probably all we need is a regular discriminant, which should mean nonzero discriminant as we are working in polynomial rings over $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg forgive the imprecision. The charpoly of the generic matrix has algebraically independent coefficients. For the discriminant, yes - nonzero in $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I thought it's reasonable to call a monic with algebraically independent coefficients initial..

Comment: Random thought: What about decomposing $f$ instead of $A$? Say we want to prove the spectral mapping theorem in the form $\chi_{f\left(A\right)} = f_*\chi_A$, where $f_*$ denotes the canonical on-the-roots-action of $f$ on polynomials. It suffices to show that $\det\left(f\left(A\right)\right) = \operatorname{Res}\left(f, \chi_A\right)$, where $\operatorname{Res}$ means the resultant for appropriate degrees. For polynomiality reasons, it suffices to prove this when $f$ is the generic polynomial whose coefficients are indeterminates. ...

Comment: ... For homogeneity reasons, we can WLOG assume that $f$ is actually monic, since we can always achieve this by dividing by the leading coefficient (in the appropriate localization). Hence, in a splitting ring of $f$, we can write $f$ as a product of factors of the form $x - r_i$. Thus, for multiplicativity reasons, we can WLOG assume that $f$ is $x - r$ for a single scalar $r$. But then our claim becomes $\det\left(A-rI\right) = \chi_A\left(r\right)$, which is obvious.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I don't really know anything about resultants (yet) and wish to avoid them. But the story I outlined above makes sense, no?

Comment: I'm not sure, and it is hard to tell based on a sketch like this. But resultants aren't a very hard concept. If the case when $f$ is monic is sufficient for you, then you can just pass to the splitting ring of $f$, write $f$ as $\prod_{i=1}^m \left(x-r_i\right)$, and the claim becomes $\det\left(f\left(A\right)\right) = \prod_{i=1}^m \chi_A\left(r_i\right)$.